# My Openzepplin ERC-721 import is not compiling

Tags: solidity, erc-721, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, version-pragma

Creating a minting capability for my dApp. Cannot compile due to solidity version error I believe.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract BCVT is ERC721, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("BC@VT", "BC@VT") {}

    function safeMint(address to) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }
```

I am using scaffold-eth if this helps with the context. What should I do to ensure that these work. I have tried using Openzepplin's docs.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried on remix with solidity compiler 0.8.17 and it worked..

How are you compiling it?

Comment: Harry commented: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

Im using vscode i assume its clang. It worked for me on remix too so I am assuming I need to update the vscode compiler.

Comment: Check your solc-select to see which version is being used and use npm install @openzeppelin/contracts to be sure. Hope this helps!